# Как быть, если точности дат в mysql и html не совпадают?

Tags: mysql, html5

Дело в том, что мне нужна точность либо до секунды, либо до минуты. В `mysql` самые близкие типы - `date`(до дня) и `datetime`(до секунды). В `html` же `date`(до дня) и `date`+`time`/`datetime`(до минуты). Как быть, если точности не совпадают? Заставлять писать пользователя не хочется, да и хранить лишнее(секунды) не хочется, плюс это позволит выстрелить себе в ногу. Как решить сей конфуз?

Comment: Секунды для хранения занимают 6 бит. Это меньше байта. Так что даже если бы тип данных без секунд и существовал у MySQL, он занимал бы в ровности столько же сколько и обычный datetime. Так что вводите на клиенте ровно столько, сколько считаете нужным (кстати в html вы можете сделать любую маску ввода и типов данных там вообще нет), а храните конечно в datetime

Comment: @Mike А как в `html` можно сделать ввод секунд через `UI`?